# Error installing Magento backup on localhost

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to install a backup of Magento on local server to test that everything works to perfection before uploading to the server.

I returned the following error and can not find solution to it, please i need your help.

```
There has been an error processing your request
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Trace:
#0 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Statement\Pdo\Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Zend\Db\Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...', Array)
#5 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...', Array)
#6 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#7 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(378): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_query('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#8 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(983): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->raw_fetchRow('SHOW TABLE STAT...')
#9 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2510): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->showTableStatus('core_cache_opti...', NULL)
#10 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Cache.php(58): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->isTableExists('core_cache_opti...')
#11 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(1183): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(413): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(343): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 C:\wamp-nuevo3\www\scshackeo\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Comment: Have you updated your database configuration credentilals at `app/etc/local.xml`. (i)Flush all cache. (ii)Re-Index all data. (iii)Flush all cache. You may delete cache files from var/cache/

Comment: You may take more idea from following stuff.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538560/how-to-bring-live-magento-site-to-localhost-without-effecting-live-site

http://insync.co.in/how-to-install-magento-on-wamp-server-localhost-localcomputer/

Answer (score 1):

Change DB configuration in file

> app/etc/local.xml

as per your local setup and open db table

> core_config_data

change following value as per your local setup

> web/unsecure/base_url

and

> web/secure/base_url